# Tensorflow tf.map_fn errors

Tags: python, tensorflow

```py
    a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 1], [4, 5, 6, 1], [7, 8, 9, 1]])
    mul = tf.constant([1, 3, 2])
    result = []
    for i in range(3):
        print(a[i], mul[i])
        result.append(tf.tile(a[i], [mul[i]]))

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print([r.eval() for r in result])
```

correct result :

[array([1, 2, 3, 1]), array([4, 5, 6, 1, 4, 5, 6, 1, 4, 5, 6, 1]), array([7, 8, 9, 1, 7, 8, 9, 1])]

```
while run below with tf.map_fn, it will fail
```

```py
    c = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 1], [4, 5, 6, 1], [7, 8, 9, 1]])
    x = tf.constant([1, 3, 1])

    def cc(b, t):
        print(b.shape, t)
        print(type(b), type(t))
        return tf.tile(b, [t])


    d = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t: cc(t[0], t[1]), elems=(c, x))
```

Here is the error trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py", line 297, in assert_same_structure
>       expand_composites)
>   ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.

First structure:

`type=tuple str=(tf.int32, tf.int32)`

Second structure:

```
type=Tensor str=Tensor("map/while/Tile:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32)
```

More specifically: Substructure `"type=tuple str=(tf.int32, tf.int32)`" is a sequence, while substructure "type=Tensor str=Tensor("map/while/Tile:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32)" is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.map_fn` cannot handle your situation. Basically, it needs *consistently shaped* output after each time it performs an operation. Let's take your example. `tf.map_fn` will do the following.

```
map => [1,2,3,1], [1] => returns a 4 element long vector
map => [4,5,6,1], [3] => returns a 12 element long vector
map => [7,8,9,1], [2] => returns a 8 element long vector
```

So when the map_fn checks what the outputs going to be for each row, it sees that the shapes going to be inconsistent. That's what the error is about.

So for this, your only option (from what I see) is to use `tf.unstack` (if using TF 1.x) which is equivalent to iterating rows in TF 2.0 (the first approach in your question).

If you need it to be a tensor at the end, you can have it as a `RaggedTensor`.

```
c = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 1], [4, 5, 6, 1], [7, 8, 9, 1]])
x = tf.constant([1, 3, 2])

def cc(b, t):
    return tf.tile(b, [t])

unstack_c = tf.unstack(c)
unstack_x = tf.unstack(x)

vals = []
for rc, rx in zip(unstack_c, unstack_x):
  vals.append(tf.reshape(cc(rc, rx),[1,-1]))

res = tf.ragged.stack(vals)
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the root cause. And I tried your solution it works for me in my case as the tensor c and tensor x is constant tensor. However it does not work when c and x are defined with tf.placeholder([None, None, 3])  tf.placeholder([None, None])  . The first dim of c and x is None which is batch_size,  the sencond dim of c and x None is same for both of it, for example, c shape  [1, 3,10] ,x :shape [1,3] .