# map_fn and tf.keras.layers.Input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, tf.keras

I have an input, which consists of two integers, start and end.
And I'd like to generate a tensor that contains integers from the start and the end.
For example, given (2, 5) as the input, I'd like to generate (2,3,4,5)
Here is my attempt:

```
start_end_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.int32, name="start_end")
tf.map_fn(lambda row: tf.range(row[0], row[1]), start_end_input, dtype=(tf.int32, tf.int32))
```

And I got this:

```
self._tensor_array = [None for _ in range(size)]
TypeError: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Any thought?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this TF2 or TF1?

Comment: It is tf2.0. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you need to use `keras.Input` layer here. But assuming you're okay to not use this layer (because it complicates accessing elements separately e.g. `x[0]`). Since you're using TF 2.0, I hope you are okay to use a numpy array or `tf.Tensor` directly. If not, let me know and I will try to see a way to incorporate the `keras.Input` layer.

But I mainly wanted to point out the error you'll run into (even if you get the above to go pass this error) and what performance differences you can expect for some of the working solutions. The short story is `tf.map_fn` cannot handle cases where variable sized outputs are returned after each row transformation. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59331996/tensorflow-tf-map-fn-errors/59332148#59332148). This is the case with your problem as `tf.range` will return varying size rows.

But if you are certain that these range bounds fall under a reasonable upper bound (e.g. the maximum of the ranges would be 1000), you can use `tf.map_fn` as follows. Basically, we are padding each result of the row transformation so that all of them will have the same length.

```
m = tf.reduce_max(a)

def range_with_map(a):
    o = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.concat([tf.range(x[0],x[1]), tf.ones(shape=[x[0]+m-x[1]+1], dtype=tf.int32)*-1], axis=0), a, dtype=tf.int32)
    b = tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(o, padding=-1)
    return b

%timeit range_with_map(a)
```

This ran in,

> 18.3 ms ± 1.58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

and you can further improve performance with `@tf.function`

```
@tf.function
def range_with_map_v2(a):
    o = tf.map_fn(
        lambda x: tf.concat([tf.range(x[0],x[1]), tf.ones(shape=[x[0]+m-x[1]+1], dtype=tf.int32)*-1], axis=0), 
        a, dtype=tf.int32) 
    b = tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(o, padding=-1)
    return b
```

> 6.63 ms ± 304 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

But if this is not an option, the best approach I can see is using a for loop.

```
def range_with_for_loop(a):
    res = []
    for r in a:
        res.append(tf.reshape(tf.range(r[0],r[1]),[1,-1]))        
    return tf.ragged.stack(res)
```

No need to say that this has the worst performance

> 26.1 ms ± 1.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

**Note**: All performance is w.r.t. my machine which has Nvidia GTX 960

Answer (score 0):

[tf.ragged.range](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ragged/range) takes a vector of limits (and optionally vectors of starts and steps), and returns a [RaggedTensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor) containing the requested ranges.  E.g.:

```
>>> tf.ragged.range([0, 5, 8], [3, 3, 12])
<tf.RaggedTensor [[0, 1, 2], [], [8, 9, 10, 11]]>
```

If you want to wrap this in Keras, it would look something like this:

```
>>> model = tf.keras.Sequential([
...     tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.int32, name="start_end"),
...     tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda row: tf.ragged.range(row[:,0], row[:,1]))])
>>> model.predict([[1, 10], [5, 8], [2, 4]])
<tf.RaggedTensor [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [5, 6, 7], [2, 3]]>
```